# Any way to easily ensure zef is pulling latest versions of raku modules?

Tags: raku, zef

I recently [filed an issue here](https://github.com/CurtTilmes/raku-nativehelpers-callback/issues/4) about zef downloading a stale version of a module, [NativeHelpers::Callback](https://raku.land/cpan:CTILMES/NativeHelpers::Callback) which was failing when I tried to install it with `zef install NativeHelpers::Callback`. I had to clone the module to my local machine from github and install it from there to get it to work.

I'm slightly confused as to how/why this happened with this module. The raku.land website provides a link to the github repo and yet [REA only has version 0.1 tarballed.](https://github.com/Raku/REA/tree/main/archive/N/NativeHelpers::Callback). But when I open up the [META6.json file for the module on github,](https://github.com/CurtTilmes/raku-nativehelpers-callback/blob/master/META6.json) it says version 0.2. I'm wondering why zef does not recognize and find this new version? And why does raku.land still shown as a CPAN module on raku.land when it's no longer on CPAN?

And my bigger question is how do I ensure zef installs the newest versions of modules? Is the problem I ran into here common? Should I manually check each module to ensure I'm getting the latest version?

Thanks.

Comment: Rawley's answer has it about right as far as it goes as far as I know. But it doesn't describe the underlying sea change in the ecosytem that was underway in 2022 with the switchover date planned to be December 31st, couple weeks ago. If you're not up to date on that, please read [Something old, something borrowed, something new, something stashed](https://raku-advent.blog/2022/12/09/day-9-something-old-something-borrowed-something-new-something-stashed/) and [its reddit/r/rakulang thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/rakulang/comments/zgspty/day_9_something_old_something_borrowed_something/).

Comment: no need tp 'download and install local' just go ```zef install https://github.com/CurtTilmes/raku-nativehelpers-callback.git```

Comment: Hi @StevieD. Is Rawley's answer acceptable or do you need more info / a better answer?

Answer (score 9):

I think this is because the owner of the module hasn't pushed the version `0.2` dist yet. You will have to build from source until the owner runs `fez upload`. It seems `raku.land` and the other sites to view dists, only know of a `0.1`.

As far as I know, `zef` will only distribute versions that have been uploaded. It does not keep track of the version within `META6.json` files on git, it only sees the `META6.json` when the owner uploads.

You could also install the version on GitHub with:

```
zef install https://github.com/CurtTilmes/raku-nativehelpers-callback
```